# how can I determine when Google Maps loadGeoJson completes?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js, typescript

I have a scenario where users can store their mapping styling. When a user navigates back to that page with the map it should display the map the way it was previously.

The user can change colors of geographies, and borders as well as apply thematic styles based on demographic information.

With the release of the new loadGeoJson I have had great success with speeding up my application, Initially I was drawing all of the geographies myself, via JS. This was causeing some memory issues at around 1500 geographies.  This new functionality decreases it significantly.  I am choosing to generate the Features objects on the server side and just pass a URL to the map for rendering. This URL is passed in along with all of the other style information to rebuild the map as it was previously.

The problem I'm encountering, is when I attempt to apply the stylings, the map hasn't retrieved its list of features to be displayed on the map.

Looking through the documenation I don't see any events specifically for the loadGeoJson method, but did see for addfeature and setgeometry, but neither of these events get raised when using the loadGeoJson method.

This has all been written in Typescript and tries to adhere to a pretty strict MVVM approach using Knockout to handle all of UI changes for me via binding.

Is there another event I can tie into to see when this method has completed so I can apply my styles appropriately?

Is there another approach where I can bake in a 'wait' somewhere?  .

Comment: Could you link the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to `addFeature` event which will be fired for each feature in your json. e.g. if you use https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json six events are raised *after* the json request is completed i.e. when google api starts adding the features from the json file:

[image]

You can see the demo here : http://jsbin.com/ofutUbA/4/edit

Comment: *...events are raised after the json request is completed...* So with the first `addFeature` event we can safely assume that all json data are received? Thanks.

Comment: @AntoJurković yes if the feature name matches something that can only come from the JSON. I suspect its true even otherwise since we are subscribing to `.data.addListener` it will only raise events for features created from `.data` and therefore `loadGeoJson` but they've obfuscated the code and I can't look inside

Comment: Thanks that did it. I was adding my listener to the map, not to data. which was why it wasn't being raised.

Answer (score 12):

addfeature event is definitely invoked by loadGeoJson, if isn't for you is some setup error.

loadGeoJson has an optional callback parameter what is invoked after all features were loaded and has the features as parameter.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference

> loadGeoJson(url:string, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions,
>   callback?:function(Array))

You can signal your code from this callback that it can continue processing.

```
map.data.loadGeoJson('google.json', null, function (features) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds); // or do other stuff what requires all features loaded
});
```

You could also wrap loadGeoJson into a promise and resolve the promise in loadGeoJson's callback.

```
function loadGeoJson(url, options) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        map.data.loadGeoJson(url, options, function (features) {
            resolve(features);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });

    return promise;
}

// Somewhere else in your code:
var promise = loadGeoJson('studs.json');

promise.then(function (features) {
    // Do stuff
});

promise.catch(function (error) {
    // Handle error
});
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm using your solution here! Works great, had a question on how to error trap if the json is NOT valid. I can't seem to trap that error. I'm loading from a json file that could change and want to tell the user the json file is not valid...

Currently I only get " Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property "features": at index 42: in property "geometry": in property "geometries": at index 1: in property "coordinates": at index 0: first and last positions are not equal" in Chrome... can't seem to catch this... Thank you in advance if anyone knows??

Comment: @Tim If loadGeoJson throws an exception you can embed it into a try-catch block. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, stuck the try catch just like you have it and chrome just wouldn't catch it. Thus the reason for my question. Thank you though for responding. ..

Answer (score 0):

One would assume, if you are using knockout, to maybe bind onto some listeners, or attach listeners to an event.

Most events through JavaScript always have a callback function, this is good practive so that once a function has finished executing some long `I/O` or `Database` query it will immediately execute that function. Obviously that callback will be defined by you.

```
someLongTimeFunction(function (data) {
  // usually this callback will be fired when the function has finished.
});
```

If you are familiar with knockout, then you would know that once the data has been retrieved and you pass through an `observable` that `observable` would update its binding.

Here is the link for extending observables: [knockout js](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

As far as I can understand from you question, this `loadGeoJson`, is it server side? If so, you do a long poll from client side and tie into that:

```
function doRequest() {
  var request = $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'loadGeoJson',
    data: data,
  });

  request.done(function(data, result) {
    if (result !== "success") {
      setTimeout(doRequest, 10000);
    }
  });
}
```