# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I tried to find an answer to this question all over the internet. I found one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174806/google-maps-api-v3-data-layer-ids-undefined), but it seems no one was able to give the right answer.

1. I was trying out an example from the Google Maps API website https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/combining-data. I only made a few changes to your code in order to use census data for a different country.
2. I changed the links so that it would access my own json files. In region.geojson you have all the coordinates for Turkish provinces and in test.json you have the census data for each province.
3. I put the census data in the same format but when the loadCensusData function hits
   map.data
             .getFeatureById(stateId)
             .setProperty('census_variable', censusVariable);

while iterating it gives me the following error, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setProperty' of undefined".
If I comment this out it will proceed the iteration until it ends but the problem is that I will not be able to use 'census_variable' as it has not been set.
4. If I change the links to point back to the US census data, it works again as expected.

Any ideas how I can solve this error? Or do you know what is causing this?

Please see the code for my map below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Mashups with google.maps.Data</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
        .nicebox {
          position: absolute;
          text-align: center;
          font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
          z-index: 5;
          box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -4px #333;
          padding: 5px 10px;
          background: rgb(255,255,255);
          background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(245,245,245,1) 100%);
          border: rgb(229, 229, 229) 1px solid;
        }
        #controls {
          top: 10px;
          left: 110px;
          width: 360px;
          height: 45px;
        }
        #data-box {
          top: 10px;
          left: 500px;
          height: 45px;
          line-height: 45px;
          display: none;
        }
        #census-variable {
          width: 360px;
          height: 20px;
        }
        #legend { display: flex; display: -webkit-box; padding-top: 7px }
        .color-key {
          background: linear-gradient(to right,
            hsl(5, 69%, 54%) 0%,
            hsl(29, 71%, 51%) 17%,
            hsl(54, 74%, 47%) 33%,
            hsl(78, 76%, 44%) 50%,
            hsl(102, 78%, 41%) 67%,
            hsl(127, 81%, 37%) 83%,
            hsl(151, 83%, 34%) 100%);
          flex: 1;
          -webkit-box-flex: 1;
          margin: 0 5px;
          text-align: left;
          font-size: 1.0em;
          line-height: 1.0em;
        }
        #data-value { font-size: 2.0em; font-weight: bold }
        #data-label { font-size: 2.0em; font-weight: normal; padding-right: 10px; }
        #data-label:after { content: ':' }
        #data-caret { margin-left: -5px; display: none; font-size: 14px; width: 14px}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="controls" class="nicebox">
      <div>
      <select id="census-variable">
        <option value="test">Fertility rate 2015</option>
        <option value="https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/DP05_0017E">Median age</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      <div id="legend">
        <div id="census-min">min</div>
        <div class="color-key"><span id="data-caret">&#x25c6;</span></div>
        <div id="census-max">max</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-box" class="nicebox">
      <label id="data-label" for="data-value"></label>
      <span id="data-value"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var mapStyle = [{
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'off'}]
      }, {
        'featureType': 'landscape',
        'elementType': 'geometry',
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#fcfcfc'}]
      }, {
        'featureType': 'water',
        'elementType': 'geometry',
        'stylers': [{'visibility': 'on'}, {'color': '#bfd4ff'}]
      }];
      var map;
      var censusMin = Number.MAX_VALUE, censusMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;

      function initMap() {

        // load the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 40, lng: -100},
          zoom: 4,
          styles: mapStyle
        });


        // set up the style rules and events for google.maps.Data
        map.data.setStyle(styleFeature);
        map.data.addListener('mouseover', mouseInToRegion);
        map.data.addListener('mouseout', mouseOutOfRegion);

        // wire up the button
        var selectBox = document.getElementById('census-variable');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(selectBox, 'change', function() {
          clearCensusData();
          loadCensusData(selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value);
        });

        // state polygons only need to be loaded once, do them now
        loadMapShapes();

      }

      /** Loads the state boundary polygons from a GeoJSON source. */
      function loadMapShapes() {
        // load US state outline polygons from a GeoJson file
        map.data.loadGeoJson('region.geojson', { idPropertyName: 'meso:name_local' });

        // wait for the request to complete by listening for the first feature to be
        // added
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.data, 'addfeature', function() {
          google.maps.event.trigger(document.getElementById('census-variable'),
              'change');
        });
      }

      /**
       * Loads the census data from a simulated API call to the US Census API.
       *
       * @param {string} variable
       */
      function loadCensusData(variable) {
        // load the requested variable from the census API (using local copies)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', variable + '.json');
        xhr.onload = function() {
          var censusData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          censusData.shift(); // the first row contains column names
          censusData.forEach(function(row) {
            var censusVariable = parseFloat(row[0]);
            var stateId = row[1];
            console.log('StateId row[0] '+censusVariable);
            console.log('censusVariable row[1] '+stateId);

            // keep track of min and max values
            if (censusVariable < censusMin) {
              censusMin = censusVariable;
            }
            if (censusVariable > censusMax) {
              censusMax = censusVariable;
            }

            // update the existing row with the new data
            map.data
              .getFeatureById(stateId)
              .setProperty('census_variable');
          });

          // update and display the legend
          document.getElementById('census-min').textContent =
              censusMin.toLocaleString();
          document.getElementById('census-max').textContent =
              censusMax.toLocaleString();
        };
        xhr.send();
      }

      /** Removes census data from each shape on the map and resets the UI. */
      function clearCensusData() {
        censusMin = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        censusMax = -Number.MAX_VALUE;
        map.data.forEach(function(row) {
          row.setProperty('census_variable', undefined);
        });
        document.getElementById('data-box').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.display = 'none';
      }

      /**
       * Applies a gradient style based on the 'census_variable' column.
       * This is the callback passed to data.setStyle() and is called for each row in
       * the data set.  Check out the docs for Data.StylingFunction.
       *
       * @param {google.maps.Data.Feature} feature
       */
      function styleFeature(feature) {
        var low = [5, 69, 54];  // color of smallest datum
        var high = [151, 83, 34];   // color of largest datum

        // delta represents where the value sits between the min and max
        var delta = (feature.getProperty('census_variable') - censusMin) /
            (censusMax - censusMin);

        var color = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          // calculate an integer color based on the delta
          color[i] = (high[i] - low[i]) * delta + low[i];
        }

        // determine whether to show this shape or not
        var showRow = true;
        if (feature.getProperty('census_variable') == null ||
            isNaN(feature.getProperty('census_variable'))) {
          showRow = false;
        }

        var outlineWeight = 0.5, zIndex = 1;
        if (feature.getProperty('state') === 'hover') {
          outlineWeight = zIndex = 2;
        }

        return {
          strokeWeight: outlineWeight,
          strokeColor: '#fff',
          zIndex: zIndex,
          fillColor: 'hsl(' + color[0] + ',' + color[1] + '%,' + color[2] + '%)',
          fillOpacity: 0.75,
          visible: showRow
        };
      }

      /**
       * Responds to the mouse-in event on a map shape (state).
       *
       * @param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e
       */
      function mouseInToRegion(e) {
        // set the hover state so the setStyle function can change the border
        e.feature.setProperty('state', 'hover');

        var percent = (e.feature.getProperty('census_variable') - censusMin) /
            (censusMax - censusMin) * 100;

        // update the label
        document.getElementById('data-label').textContent =
            e.feature.getProperty('NAME');
        document.getElementById('data-value').textContent =
            e.feature.getProperty('census_variable').toLocaleString();
        document.getElementById('data-box').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('data-caret').style.paddingLeft = percent + '%';
      }

      /**
       * Responds to the mouse-out event on a map shape (state).
       *
       * @param {?google.maps.MouseEvent} e
       */
      function mouseOutOfRegion(e) {
        // reset the hover state, returning the border to normal
        e.feature.setProperty('state', 'normal');
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my JSON file with Census Data (test.json):

```
[["DP02_0066PE","region"],
["2.31", "Adana"],
["2.86", "Adıyaman"],
["2.06", "Afyonkarahisar"],
["3.80", "Ağrı"],
["2.24", "Aksaray"],
["1.79", "Amasya"],
["1.76", "Ankara"],
["1.96", "Antalya"],
["2.15", "Ardahan"],
["1.73", "Artvin"],
["1.85", "Aydın"],
["1.64", "Balıkesir"],
["1.58", "Bartın"],
["3.24", "Batman"],
["2.07", "Bayburt"],
["1.71", "Bilecik"],
["2.42", "Bingöl"],
["3.40", "Bitlis"],
["1.59", "Bolu"],
["1.77", "Burdur"],
["1.91", "Bursa"],
["1.53", "Çanakkale"],
["1.77", "Çankırı"],
["1.83", "Çorum"],
["1.84", "Denizli"],
["3.21", "Diyarbakır"],
["1.85", "Düzce"],
["1.53", "Edirne"],
["1.97", "Elazığ"],
["1.82", "Erzincan"],
["2.51", "Erzurum"],
["1.55", "Eskişehir"],
["3.15", "Gaziantep"],
["1.62", "Giresun"],
["1.66", "Gümüşhane"],
["2.69", "Hakkâri"],
["2.70", "Hatay"],
["3.04", "Iğdır"],
["1.70", "Isparta"],
["1.88", "İstanbul"],
["1.72", "İzmir"],
["2.61", "Kahramanmaraş"],
["1.56", "Karabük"],
["2.10", "Karaman"],
["2.64", "Kars"],
["1.62", "Kastamonu"],
["2.18", "Kayseri"],
["2.92", "Kilis"],
["1.71", "Kırıkkale"],
["1.54", "Kırklareli"],
["1.79", "Kırşehir"],
["2.06", "Kocaeli"],
["2.18", "Konya"],
["1.58", "Kütahya"],
["2.01", "Malatya"],
["1.92", "Manisa"],
["3.41", "Mardin"],
["2.15", "Mersin"],
["1.75", "Muğla"],
["3.45", "Muş"],
["1.96", "Nevşehir"],
["2.18", "Niğde"],
["1.81", "Ordu"],
["2.47", "Osmaniye"],
["1.78", "Rize"],
["1.92", "Sakarya"],
["1.80", "Samsun"],
["4.38", "Şanlıurfa"],
["3.55", "Siirt"],
["1.72", "Sinop"],
["4.01", "Şırnak"],
["1.96", "Sivas"],
["1.93", "Tekirdağ"],
["1.72", "Tokat"],
["1.85", "Trabzon"],
["1.69", "Tunceli"],
["1.73", "Uşak"],
["3.36", "Van"],
["1.77", "Yalova"],
["1.99", "Yozgat"],
["1.55", "Zonguldak"]]
```

The other file with all the geoJSON data is way too big to post here. But if necessary I can find a way to share it with you.

Comment: Your issue here is there's no error check in those functions for null values. There may be more to it however. Just be sure the object you're passing to the function has the properties that are being changed.

Comment: `map.data.getFeatureById(stateId)` is returning undefined

Comment: Probably `stateId` isn't an id in the JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. To be frank, it was a pretty stupid mistake from my part. I guess I was already tired and didn't realize my mistake so I'd like to thank everyone who commented on my question as it helped me realize what I did wrong.

There are two JSON files. One that contains the coordinates, let's call it ***coordinates.geojson*** and the other contains the census data, let's call it ***census.json***.

Now for these lines of code to work,

```
map.data
     .getFeatureById(stateId)
     .setProperty('census_variable');
```

you must make sure that *stateId* corresponds to both the id in the ***census.json*** file as well as the id in the ***coordinates.geojson*** file.

In my case the stateId from the ***census.json*** file did not equal the first id/state in ***coordinates.geojson*** which was Aydin. Whereas ***census.json*** started with Adana, then Adıyaman etc.

Therefore I had to change the order of the census data to

```
[["DP02_0066PE","region"],
["1.85", "Aydin"],
["1.72", "Izmir"],
["1.64", "Balikesir"],
["1.53", "Çanakkale"],
["1.53", "Edirne"],
["1.54", "Kirklareli"],
["1.93", "Tekirdag"],
["1.71", "Bilecik"],
["1.91", "Bursa"],
["1.88", "Istanbul"],
["2.06", "Kocaeli"],
["1.92", "Sakarya"],
["1.59", "Bolu"],
["1.55", "Eskisehir"],
["1.62", "Kastamonu"],
["1.96", "Antalya"],
["2.06", "Afyon"],
["1.77", "Burdur"],
["1.84", "Denizli"],
["1.70", "Isparta"],
["1.58", "Kütahya"],
["1.92", "Manisa"],
["1.75", "Mugla"],
["2.86", "Adiyaman"],
["1.97", "Elazig"],
["2.61", "Kahramanmaras"],
["2.01", "Malatya"],
["2.15", "Içel"],
["1.79", "Kirsehir"],
["2.18", "Kayseri"],
["1.96", "Nevsehir"],
["2.70", "Hatay"],
["1.79", "Amasya"],
["1.83", "Çorum"],
["1.62", "Giresun"],
["1.81", "Ordu"],
["1.72", "Sinop"],
["1.96", "Sivas"],
["1.80", "Samsun"],
["1.72", "Tokat"],
["1.73", "Artvin"],
["2.51", "Erzurum"],
["1.82", "Erzincan"],
["1.78", "Rize"],
["1.85", "Trabzon"],
["3.80", "Agri"],
["2.42", "Bingöl"],
["3.21", "Diyarbakir"],
["3.45", "Mus"],
["3.40", "Bitlis"],
["1.76", "Ankara"],
["1.77", "Çankiri"],
["1.55", "Zonguldak"],
["2.18", "Konya"],
["2.10", "Karaman"],
["1.73", "Usak"],
["3.15", "Gaziantep"],
["4.38", "Sanliurfa"],
["2.31", "Adana"],
["1.71", "Kirikkale"],
["2.18", "Nigde"],
["2.24", "Aksaray"],
["1.99", "Yozgat"],
["1.66", "Gümüshane"],
["2.07", "Bayburt"],
["2.64", "Kars"],
["3.41", "Mardin"],
["3.24", "Batman"],
["3.55", "Siirt"],
["4.01", "Sirnak"],
["1.69", "Tunceli"],
["2.69", "Hakkari"],
["3.36", "Van"],
["2.15", "Ardahan"],
["3.04", "Igdir"],
["2.92", "Kilis"],
["2.47", "Osmaniye"],
["1.77", "Yalova"],
["1.85", "Düzce"],
["1.56", "Karabük"],
["1.58", "Bartin"]]
```

Last but not least, please note that I removed all the specific Turkish characters such as ğ, ı and ş because the id from ***coordinates.geojson*** where spelled without them. Hence I changed Ağrı to Agri and so forth.

I guess it would have been better had I used numbers as IDs instead of names.

I hope this will prevent other people of making the same mistake.